# add left and right margins to Grouped UITableView ios 8

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode6

I would like to add left and right margins to the grouped UITableView like youtube application see the below screenshot:
[image]

Please any suggestions!!
Many thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Put the table view as a subview to another view. This enables you to layout the position and size of the table view as you wish.

Comment: I am trying to do the simplest way because I have UITableViewController, so I decided to put change the style to grouped maybe it will work like the youtube app?

Comment: I think this is the simplest way. Grouped table views come with many differences. You have to decide it this fits you needs.

Comment: look in fact what I need is to have a view like youtube app, so I am asking if the grouped table views can  solve it, or I have to put the table view as a subview to another view?

Comment: I don't know the youtube app. Why don't you just try it. And change it if it doesn't fit later.